# How to trigger an unpause using audio controls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio

Controlling the audio using the following code isn't working. If i click button which `onclick` calls `playpause()` it pauses the audio. But on again clicking it isn't resuming.

```
    var audio=new Audio("music.mp3");
    function music() {
        audio.play();
        audio.loop="true";
    }

    function playpause() {

        if(audio.play)
        {
            audio.pause();
        }
        else  if(audio.pause)
        {
            audio.play();
        }
    }
```

However if i use following, It is enabling pause and play using the same button

```
    var audio=new Audio("music.mp3");
    function music() {
        audio.play();
        audio.loop="true";
    }
    var count=0;
    function playpause() {

        if(count%2==0)
        {
            audio.pause();
        }
        else
        {
            audio.play();

        }
        count++;
    }
```

What's wrong with the 1st one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 audio tag doesn't provide a 'play' property like you are trying to use in your code but it does provide a 'paused' property which by calling it returns the opposite Boolean. You would need to use it to query the state of the audio element.

Like this:

```
If(audio.paused) {
  audio.play();
}
else {
  audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the solution. But one thing, if the following is a valid snippet? :

Comment: If(audio.play) {
  audio.pause();
}
else {
  audio.play();
}

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 'paused' is valid. 'play' property isn't